# Getting net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, glassfish, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm getting this error on Chrome (v 59.0.3071.109), I have tried a couple of answers without any luck.

This is what shows in the security tab:

```
The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name extension containing a domain name or IP address
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/java-security-tutorial-%E2%80%93-step) to create the certificate with this values:

```
CN = localhost
OU = ort
O = ort
L = montevideo
S = MVD
C = UY
```

And this is my host `https://localhost:8181/Gateway-war/`

So far I have tried:

- Enabling this flag `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`
- Adding this `--ignore-certificate-errors` to the Chrome Shortcut, it shows a message saying this command isn't allowed because it affects security and stability
- Using [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917227/3695939): `reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome /v EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors /t REG_DWORD /d 1`

In all the cases I restarted Chrome before trying it out.

Maybe my `CN` should be something more than localhost?
Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 5):

When you have configured your certificate right, you don't have to do all those workarounds to make it work. All you have to do is to add the `SubjectAltName` extension in your certificate to make the browser happy.

I assume you must be using a self-signed certificate. If so, your certificate must look like this for the 'SubjectAltName' extension. You could use the [keystore-explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/) (opensource GUI for `keytool`) to generate your certificate like this:

[image: certificate]

If it is a CA signed, you need to make sure you send these extension attributes in your CSR.

Comment: So how in fact do you do this for a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a certificate with the "Subject Alternative Name". If using windows one can use PowerShell. The cerificate will be stored in the windows register. You can access the certificates via certml.msc which can then be exported to a drive in certmgr.msc. An example of a certificate with "Subject Alternative Name" is bellow by using the TextExtension parameter on New-SelfSignedCertificate.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -FriendlyName "My Network Name" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.17={text}dns=*.example.com&ipaddress=192.168.1.1")
```